# Retrofit 2 Retry a request with alternative baseUrl

Tags: java, android, retrofit

About Retrofit 2.

I'm ussing this solution for retry a request with Retrofit 2: [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840088/2038286)

is there a way to change the baseUrl in the retry?

or there is another way to retry a request changing the baseUrl.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: it's exactly the same as the reference.