# Optimal way to handle network disconnection

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-networking

I am new to Android and I am trying to figure out the best way to handle the situation when a user does not have a network connection. I am using Retrofit2 with OkHttp and I have tried multiple solutions.

**First approach:**

OkHttp interceptor:

```
new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            // try the request
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);


            private final SuperActivityToast warningToast = new 
            SuperActivityToast(currentActivity, new Style(), Style.TYPE_BUTTON).setIndeterminate(true);
            warningToast.setText("Currently offline").show;

            while (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                // retry the request
                response = chain.proceed(request);
            }

            // otherwise just pass the original response on
            return response;
        }
    }
```

So basically I keep retrying a request up until the user has a network connection (this is the basic idea, I will implement a check to differentiate between the case when the user has no network and when the issue comes from the server), but I am aware that it is not efficient. Also the while loop is never accessed (I've used debugging mode with breakpoints to check), the code stops at: `Response response = chain.proceed(request);`, at this part the request is reloaded, and even tho' it fails again the interceptor is never reaccessed, without any errors in the console.

**Second approach:**

I have used this example: [Retrying the request using Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579754/retrying-the-request-using-retrofit-2) to implement a toast with a button for the user to retry a failed request manually but in this situation I've met a barrier: *If an activity has multiple requests a toast with a retry button will be shown for the user to retry each request separately.*

Any other ways I have missed? The main question is: **What is the best way to check for user network disconnection and allow the user to retry the request or for us to automatically retry the failed requests?**

Comment: Please check my answer, if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two solutions, which suits you better it is up to you to decide:

1) you can use Broadcast Receiver to detect network connection change, and send broadcast to all interested fragments or activities to do network call automatically when device gets internet connection.
[detailed tutorial here](http://www.androhub.com/android-detect-internet-connection-using-broadcast-receiver/)

2) You can use RxJava (I use this approach), with this simple library you get callback in observable when network be

[Github of the library - RxNetwork](https://github.com/pwittchen/ReactiveNetwork)